# Remove Commenting on Certain Pages

Tags: themes, comments

I have created some pages in wordpress like "Contact, Photo-Gallery, Services".
Problem is - on every of those pages at the bottome there is a form for commenting a page.
I do want to have this function on blog pages, BUT NOT on this "general" pages.
The question is - how can I remove commenting functions on mentioned pages?

Answer (score 1):

Found it!!!
Pages -> Quick Edit -> untick Allow Comments

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the comment part from the pages. Go to `wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/` and open `page.php`
In this page search for

```
<?php
// If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
    comments_template();
endif;
?>
```

and remove or coment this whole block or just comment out `comments_template();`